# IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder to required type

Tags: spring-security, cas, illegalstateexception

I'm getting the below error when using BCryptPasswordEncoder in CAS 4.2 (Central Authentication Service).:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder] to required type [org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.PasswordEncoder] for property 'passwordEncoder': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

I've added all the dependencies in Maven. I also checked over CAS documents, but there is no proper information about how to configure BCryptPasswordEncoder with CAS.

deployerconfigcontext.xml (Maven for compilation):

```xml
<bean id="primaryAuthenticationHandler"
  class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler"
  p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
  p:passwordEncoder-ref="passwordEncoder"
  p:sql="select PASSWORD from SD_AD_DAT_LOGIN where ACCESS_NAME=?" />
<bean id="passwordEncoder"  class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
```

I've connected CAS with the Oracle database, and it validated the plain text password correctly. Now I want to use bcrypt password encoding, and store the encode password in the database so that CAS should validate the encode password.

Help me understand the usage of BCryptPasswordEncoder with CAS.

Answer (score 0):

After some more analysis i got to know that CAS 4.2.7 doesn't support Bcrypt encoding so to use this we need to write new custom class (BCryptSearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler) to handle bcrypt encoding.

```
  deployerconfig.xml :
       <bean id="primaryAuthenticationHandler"
      class="io.wicket.cas.BCryptSearchModeSearchDatabaseAuthenticationHandler"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:tableUsers="SD_AD_DAT_LOGIN"
      p:fieldUser="ACCESS_NAME"
      p:fieldPassword="PASSWORD"
      p:passwordEncoder-ref="passwordEncoder"/>

       <bean id="passwordEncoder"    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.0.72:1521:xe" />
    <property name="username" value="PROD17102018" />
    <property name="password" value="PROD17102018" />
   </bean>
```